# Find date gaps in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

If the employee have start date and end date with history records. How can we say that there are gaps?

Sample data:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
|EmpID | StartDate   |  EndDate    |
+------+-------------+-------------+
| 555  |  7/8/2015   |  15/12/2015 |
| 555  |  16/12/2015 |  25/06/2016 |
| 555  |  28/06/2016 |  20/12/2016 | --Here 2 days gaps.  
| 555  |  21/12/2016 |  31/12/9999 |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no overlapping dates, you can use `lag` to get the previous end_date and get the difference with the current row's start_date and check if the difference > 1 (which means a gap as per the sample data shown).

```
select distinct emp_id 
from (select t.*
      ,datediff(day,lag(end_date,1,end_date) over(partition by emp_id order by start_date),start_date) as diff
      from tbl t
     ) t
where diff > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lag if it is SQL Server >= 2012 as below

```
Select *, GapDays = Coalesce(DateDiff(Day,lag(EndDate) over(partition by empid order by Startdate), StartDate)-1, 0)
    from #emp
```

Output as below:

```
+-------+------------+------------+---------+
| EmpId | StartDate  |  EndDate   | GapDays |
+-------+------------+------------+---------+
|   555 | 2015-08-07 | 2015-12-15 |       0 |
|   555 | 2015-12-16 | 2016-06-25 |       0 |
|   555 | 2016-06-28 | 2016-12-20 |       2 |
|   555 | 2016-12-21 | 9999-12-31 |       0 |
+-------+------------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
create table #emp(EmpID int,StartDate date,EndDate date)

insert into #emp values
(555,'7/8/2015',  '15/12/2015'),
(555,'16/12/2015','25/06/2016'),
(555,'28/06/2016','20/12/2016'),    --Here 2 days gaps.
(555,'21/12/2016','31/12/9999')
```

query:

```
select iq.EmpID,iq.StartDate,iq.EndDate, (DATEDIFF(day,iq.prev_date,iq.startdate)-1) as 'gap'
from
 (select *, lag(enddate) over (partition by EmpID order by empid, startdate) as prev_date
  from #emp
 )iq
where (DATEDIFF(day,iq.prev_date,iq.startdate)-1) > 0
```

output :

```
EmpID       StartDate  EndDate     gap
----------- ---------- ----------  -----
555         2016-06-28 2016-12-20  2
```